# Unable to commit a renamed file to Subversion (SVN)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit

I have been successfully committing to an SVN repository using TortoiseSVN but recently when I try to do a simple rename on a file from `Guide v1.0.docx` to `Guide v1.1.docx` in the same folder, I am unable to commit and I get the following error:

```
Error: Commit failed (details follow):  
Error: File 'C:\MyApp\Guide v1.1.docx' is out of date  
Error: File 'Guide v1.1.docx' already exists  
Error: You have to update your working copy first.
```

I attempted the following but these all result in the above error:

- Doing an SVN update on my working copy.
- Deleting the repository from my local machine, checking out fresh, and then re-adding the modified file.
- Using the repo browser to delete the file directly in the remote repository.

The `Guide v1.1.docx` does NOT exist in the repository so I'm not sure what it could be complaining about.

Comment: Try checking out _just_ the folder containing `Guide v1.0.docx` and (without opening it up in Word) try to do an [`svn move`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html) from the command-line.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the latest version of Toirtoise 1.8.1 and reverting back to 1.8.0 solved the problem.